# Docker NGINX setup to run Django project is giving invalid port specification error

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am trying to setup Docker for my django project. I believe everything is setup to run docker in my machine. Currently, the `docker version` gives following output:

```
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 17.05.0-ce
Server API version: 1.29
Go version (server): go1.7.5
Git commit (server): 89658be
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

I have setup my `docker-compose.yml` file as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: NGINX
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: DJANGO
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn loop.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - /static:/static
    expose:
      - "8000"

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: PSQL
```

`docker-compose build` successfully builds docker images and shows following message:

```
Successfully built 6b13b02488dc
Successfully tagged loopserver_web:latest
nginx uses an image, skipping
```

But, when I try to run `docker-compose up` following error occurs:

```
Creating NGINX ... 
Creating NGINX ... error

ERROR: for NGINX  Cannot create container for service nginx: invalid port specification: "None"

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot create container for service nginx: invalid port specification: "None"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

And the`server.conf` file inside `config/nginx` folder.

```
upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

# portal
server {  
  location /static/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /static/; 
    }
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
  listen 8000;
  server_name localhost;
}
```

I am using `docker` for the first time and stuck with this error. Any guidance will be very helpful.

Comment: What do you have in `./config/nginx` ?

Comment: I has `server.conf` file inside `config/nginx` folder.

Comment: The problem could be there. Can you please show it?

Comment: It seems a bug of docker-compose.https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4729

Comment: They say: *Upgrading to Python 3.4.4+ or 3.5.1+ should fix it.*

Comment: Thank you @Robert. It works with python 3.5.1+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I leave the answer here to consult in the future.*

As we investigated, it seems that there is some issue in your docker-compose version (< 1.12.0) with python3.

Bug: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4729

They recommend to upgrade to **Python 3.4.4+ or 3.5.1+**, and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

in `web` service, just add:

```
environment:
   - NGINX_HOST=foobar.com
   - NGINX_PORT=80
```

for more information: [docker nginx](https://docs.docker.com/samples/nginx/#running-nginx-in-debug-mode)

Comment: It won't work as he has not the required template (mentioned in the docs)